# How to get it REALLY right with LD_LIBRARY_PATH and linking?

Tags: c++, bash, mpi, ld, dynamic-linking

I'm repeatedly experiencing problems with libraries which are not found.

In my bashrc I have:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib2
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib3

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

These paths contain ALL folders from where I link libraries into my program with -L/lib1 -l1a -L/lib2 -l2a -L/lib3 -l3a.

Now I start my program standalone:

```
./program
```

Fine!

Then I start it with mpiexec from mpich:

```
/mpich/intel/bin/mpiexec -np 2 ./solvertest1
```

Fine!

BUT THEN I start it with gdb enabled:

```
/mpich/intel/bin/mpiexec -np 2 gdb ./solvertest1
```

Problem, libraries are not found:

```
Starting program: /my/program
/my/program: error while loading shared libraries: libirng.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I suspect that there's something wrong when the LD_LIBRARY_PATH should be propagated through all the subprocesses and shells those scripts and programs produce... What do I have to do to let every subprocess (and whatever else will be started) know where those libraries are?

Comment: If you have root access: don't use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Put all your non-system libs in `/usr/local/lib`, add that path to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, run `ldconfig` when useful.

Comment: The self-assignment in your call to `export` is redundant; `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is sufficient. Further, since the `export` command simply marks a variable *name* as exportable (it does not push a value into the environment), it can be done at any time prior to the creation of the process whose environment will consist of exported variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the program is dependent on having the right environment variables set to run, and mpiexec isn't giving it the env it needs, try something like these from the mpiexec docs:

-x , --envall
    Export all environment variables to all processes.

-E , --env name value
    Export the variable name with the content value.

Answer (score 5):

Store the library path in the `DT_RPATH` tag of your executable when linking

`-Wl,rpath=/lib1 -Wl,rpath=/lib2 -Wl,rpath=/lib3`

that way you don't need to mess with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and shell initialization.